# Some concepts do not understand about torque and angular momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque

These are the knowledge points I got from online video.I finally found that there were some things I didn’t understand.

$\sum_n F_iR_i=\tau=I_{axis}a_z$,I learned from the previous video learning that the distance of R is the distance between each object and the axis of rotation.

BUT

The next video is in the derivation of angular momentum about rotation.Before that, it is necessary to derive the angular momentum of a point $a$ and the object(This distance is the distance between the point $a$ and the object).

Because the total momentum (here is $mv$) is zero, This has nothing to do with the selection of points, which can be selected at will.So for simplicity, the rotation axis is selected.

$l=r_ap=mr_a^2w$;$I=mr_a^2=I_{axis}$;$l=I_{axis}w$

Why torque only considers the distance of the the axis of rotation and not the point, while the derivation of angular momentum needs to go from point to axis.

[image]

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by your last statement?

Comment: If this is not a thin slice, then the distance between the point and the object will produce components in other directions.What is the reason, torque only needs to consider the vertical distance of the rotation.Although the two are not the same thing, why the angular momentum needs to be considered from a point.

Comment: Maybe I don’t have some knowledge background, it is usually regarded as the distance from the axis of rotation. Because of the comparison of angular momentum, I am confused

Comment: Definition of torque and angular momentum,Torque only considers the distance between the object and the axis of rotation, not the distance between the point and the object,But angular momentum needs to consider the distance between the point and the object

Comment: The first statement is incorrect. In dynamics you measure torques about the _center of mass_ and not the axis of rotation. Only under special circumstances you would consider the distance to the pivot. Also why not consider $R=a$ and imagine a force acting on each point mass.

Comment: Thanks for your correction

Answer (score 0):

Torque on a particle is defined as $\vec r  \times \vec F$ where $\vec r$ is the distance from the *selected origin* to the point where the force $\vec F$ is applied.  The magnitude of the torque is $rFsin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec r$ and $\vec F$.  If we resolve the vector $\vec r$ into two components, one parallel to $\vec F$ and the other perpendicular to $\vec F$, the magnitude of the torque is $r_{perpendicular \enspace to \enspace F}F$; for rotation about a *fixed axis* this is the equation being used in your question above, summed over all particles (objects).

The direction of the torque is given by the right hand rule for $\vec r  \times \vec F$.

Similarly angular momentum  of a particle about a selected origin is $\vec r \times m \vec v$ where $m$ is mass and $\vec v$ is velocity; the magnitude of the angular momentum can be expressed as $r_{perpendicular \enspace to \enspace p} \vec p$, where $\vec p = m \vec v$ is the linear momentum, and $r_{perpendicular \enspace to \enspace p}$ is the component of $\vec r$ perpendicular to $\vec p$.

For a rigid body rotating about a fixed axis, the magnitude of torque is expressed as $I\alpha$ and the magnitude of the angular momentum is expressed as $I \omega$, where $I$ is the inertia of the body about the axis, and $\alpha$ and $\omega$ are the angular acceleration and the angular velocity, respectively, of each point in the body with respect to the axis.

See a good basic physics book, such as one by Halliday and Resnick.

(For general rotation of a rigid body about a point (not a fixed axis), the situation is complicated to evaluate and the inertia $I$ is a tensor.  See a physics text on mechanics such as Mechanics by Symon or Classical Mechanics by Goldstein.)

Comment: Can I ask some strange questions？If the axis of rotation points to k,The distance from a point on the axis of rotation to the object is r,r=i+k.Why for torque, only need to consider i*F.But it is much stricter for angular momentum,l=rp=(i+k)p

Comment: Thanks, it might be too difficult for me

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify the components of r for the magnitude of torque and angular momentum.   A good basic physics book (e.g., Halliday and Resnick) explains all this very well.  The use of inertia and angular acceleration and angular velocity are used for the specific case of rotation of a rigid body about a fixed axis, but the relationships are derived from the general relations for torque and angular momentum about an arbitrary origin for a system of particles (not necessarily a rigid body). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much！I noticed that the angular velocity is about the distance of the axis，But for torque, compared to angular momentum, the difference is too big，Maybe I can understand later.

Comment: You are welcome.  These are not simple concepts when you first try to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a thin mass-less rod, free to rotate around a friction-less perpendicular axle at one end.  We will attach a point mass, m, to the rod at a distance, r, from the axle.  Then (starting with the rod at rest) apply a force, F, perpendicular to the rod and axle at a distance, R, from the axle.  The torque, acting over a (short) time, t, imparts an angular impulse to the rod and the rod transmits the torque and impulse to the mass:  FRt = frt = (ma)rt = (mr)(at) = mrv = m$r^2$(v/r) = Iω.  If other forces are applied, the torques add.  If other masses are attached, the total torque is divided between them such that each has the same angular acceleration.  Not that the big, R, is measured to the point of application of a force, and the little, r, is measured to the location of a mass.  This logic can be extended to a solid object rotating about a fixed axle.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.Because of symmetry, the angular momentum in other directions will be cancelled, so the distance of the axis of rotation can be considered,I am confused because of this view.

Comment: If an object is not symmetrical, then I will calculate whether it is over!This seems very strange. Perhaps from the sense of life, because of constraints, there is no freedom of rotation in other directions. So the direction of rotation is considered?

Comment: Perhaps there will be a deeper understanding in the future, does this depend on the degree of freedom?

Comment: Clarification on my statement above：The above figure is about the angular momentum of the point and the object.L2+L1 point to k hat,Because of the addition of L3, the angular momentum cannot always be parallel to k.This is about points and objects

Comment: I correct my statement, this is also considered. Perhaps I should change the statement, the total angular momentum of the point and the object can be regarded as the angular momentum in the axial direction and the angular momentum in other vertical directions.Other directions mean to be offset because of the limitation of the rotation axis.

Comment: I can think of such a distinction as the vertical decomposition of force, and their contributions are independent!More is that we prefer the relationship of the axis of rotation,avoid complicated calculations of points to objects.

Comment: If understood in this way, the rotation in the K direction is real.But in other directions because the axis of rotation cannot be twisted, this torque will be resisted.Even if it is the relationship between a point and an object, the distance on the axis of rotation is fixed. However, the value of other directions will be different due to the different selected points. Is this kind of torque real?

Comment: In my senses, there is only the distance of the axis of rotation. Is there any offset torque in other directions. Note that this is a calculation using points and objects. Other direction seems very unreal to me.Even if it does not appear to rotate in other directions, does it do not rotate because there is no torque or the resultant torque is zero.

Comment: What I mean is that in other directions, the torsion does not exist, or the torque exists but the total torque is zero.Note that if an object does not rotate, its torque does not exist, or its torque may exist but only zero. For this direction, it is the former or the latter.

Comment: If you have separate point masses, the net torque on each (with all radii measured from a selected point) will determine the rate of change of angular momentum for each, relative to that point.  If you have a rigid object on a fixed axis, all radii are measured perpendicular to the axis.

Answer (score 0):

Both torque and angular momentum use the same moment arm calculation using 3D vectors.

$$ \vec{\rm torque} = \vec{r} \times \vec{\rm force} $$

$$ \vec{\rm ang.mom} = \vec{r} \times \vec{\rm momentum} $$

where $\times$ is the vector cross product, that disregards any parallel components of distance and only considers the perpendicular distance (called a moment arm). The vector $\vec{r}$ is measured from the origin.

The above is entirely analogous to the velocity of a point on a rotating body

$$ \vec{\rm vel} = - \vec{r} \times \vec{\omega} $$

And since you have $\vec{\rm momentum} = m\;\vec{\rm vel}$, the equation for angular momentum becomes

$$ \vec{\rm ang.mom} = \vec{r}\times ( m \, (-\vec{r}\times \vec{\omega})) = \underbrace{ -m\,\vec{r}\times \vec{r}\times }_{\rm mmoi} \vec{\omega} $$

Out of the equations above come all the planar projections that you are familiar with, like $F R = I \alpha$, or $I=m r_a^2$.

Comment: Thanks!Can you read my reply about R.W.bird below?Forget it, I'm a bit confused about points and objects.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the question and make it a bit more specific to your point of confusion. Start by trying to derive the equations of motion from point particles moving together, by summing momenta and then using Newton's second law.